# Finding Time Complexity Of This Algorithm

Tags: c, recursion, time-complexity

I'm trying to find the time complexity of this algorithm, I tried calculating it using `T(n)`, assumed that `T(n) = 2T(n-1) + Const` and got `O(n)` as a result.

```
bool sum(int arr[], int x, int n, int index){
    if(x == 0 && index == 3)
        return true;
    if(n == 0)
        return false;
    if (index == 3)
        return false;

    if(sum(arr+1, x-arr[0], n-1, index + 1))
        return true;
    return sum(arr+1, x, n-1, index);
}
```

The top call starts with index = 0. Basically I'm trying to see if there is a triple that sums to a given value x.

Am I missing something?

Comment: `T(n) = 2T(n-1) + Const` would be exponential, not linear.

Comment: Where does the 2 come from in *T(n) = 2T(n-1) + C*?

Comment: @ScottHunter It's because there are 2 recursive calls.  I think `T(n) = 2T(n-1) + Const` is too high though, because it ignores the stopping condition on `index == 3`.

Comment: I don't know whether *you* are missing something, but *I'm* confused about the nature of the `index` parameter.  Does the question assume that the complexity you want to evaluate is associated with a particular `index` (maybe 0) for the top-level call?  If not, then the stop conditions based on that parameter can be ignored because they are never exercised in the event that `sum` is called with an `index` of 4 or larger.

Comment: The top call starts with index = 0. Basically I'm trying to see if there is a triple that sums to  a given value x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `T(n) = 2T(n-1) + Const` would make T(n) be in O(2^n), not O(n). This would be the runtime if you didn't have the `index == 3` stopping condition. But this stopping condition decreases the runtime significantly.

One way to find the time complexity is to count the number of leaves in the recursion tree (i.e. number of times a stop condition was reached). Each leaf with `index == 3` corresponds to a choice of 3 out of n elements, so there are C(n, 3) such nodes. Leaves with `n == 0` and `index < 3` corresponds to a choice of 0, 1, or 2 elements, i.e. C(n, 0) + C(n, 1) + C(n, 2). The total number of leaves is thus O(n^3).

Since the number of inner nodes (calls which do not reach a stop condition and thus make recursive calls) is about equal to the number of leaves, and each call does O(1) work not including the recursive calls, the total runtime is O(n^3).

Another way to get the same result is to consider `T(n, index)`:

```
T(n, 3) = C = O(1)
T(n, 2) = T(n-1, 3) + T(n-1, 2) + C = O(n)
T(n, 1) = T(n-1, 2) + T(n-1, 1) + C = O(n^2)
T(n, 0) = T(n-1, 1) + T(n-1, 0) + C = O(n^3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that the top-level call is assumed to be made with `index == 0` (from comments), the algorithm is O(n<sup>3</sup>).  Ignore the details of the implementation, and consider more abstractly what it is doing:

- It performs a linear scan over array `arr`, where

  - for each element `e`, it performs a linear scan over the tail of `arr` starting after `e`, where

    - for each element `f`, it performs a linear scan over the tail of `arr` starting after `f`, where

      - for each element `g`, it checks whether `e + f + g == x`

The boundary case is the one in which no triplet of elements sums to `x`, and in that case the procedure does not end until all the scans are complete.  As should be clear from that description, the recursion is equivalent to a triply-nested loop.